# Raw Function decorators in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have a simple decorator in python and I am using that to decorate a function

```py
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(args):
        print("calling function")
        fn(args)
    return wrapper


@decorator
def printMyName(name):
    print(name)

printMyName('pengooX')
```

If try to write something similar in typescript it throws an error.
Below is my code

```js
function decorator(fn){
    function wrapper(args){
        console.log("calling function")
        fn(args)
    }
    return wrapper
}


@decorator
function printMyName(n){
    console.log(n)
}

printMyName('pengooX')
```

I wanted to know whether raw function decorators is supported in typescript and if not can you please explain the reasoning behind it like what issues might arise from this.
I checked typescript documentation and there isn't any discussion about raw function decorators in typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators).

Answer (score 0):

The current TC39 standard decorator proposal only covers decorating classes and class members as detailed [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators). The extension [document](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/blob/master/EXTENSIONS.md) proposes supporting decorators on functions, but that is not yet standardized.

TypeScript used to have it's own version of decorators (based on a a previous standard proposal that failed), but I would recommend against using those legacy decorators if you are starting a new project.